# Resizing a background image on UIButton

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I am trying to add a "calendar day" image to surround some text on a clickable UI button like so:

```
let button = UIButton()
let X_Offset : CGFloat = (95 * CGFloat(buttonCount) ) + 10
let scrollHeight = scrollView.bounds.height

button.frame = CGRect(x: X_Offset, y: scrollHeight/6, width: 70, height: 60)
let buttonText = event.startTime.toShortDayOfWeekString() + "\n" + event.startTime.toShortDayOfMonthString()
button.titleLabel!.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
button.titleLabel!.textAlignment = .center
button.setTitle(buttonText, for: .normal)
button.tag = i

button.backgroundColor = CompanyColor.Red.color
let image = UIImage(named: "calendarDay")
button.setBackgroundImage(image, for: .normal)
button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Roboto", size: 14)
button.layer.cornerRadius = 8
button.clipsToBounds = true
```

But the image is encroaching on the text a bit too much:
[image: encroaching image in uibutton]
How can I get the background image to scale up slightly and leave enough gap for the text?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you what you are looking for is setting `imageEdgeInsets` for `UIButton`. Setting of these properties lets you move image around besides its default position. You have to play around to get your desired result.

There are two ways you can do this. One is using `Interface Builder` and other one is programmatically. Interface builder is easiest way to go I guess. Below image shows how can you set those properties for `UIButton`.

[image: Edit these properties to get your desired result]

or try using programmatically like this

```
button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: -10, left: 32, bottom: -10, right: 50)
```

You can move title like this

```
button.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left:0, bottom: 0, right: 20)
```

**Note:** Setting `UIEdgeInsets` like this might have different result if you have dynamic size button e.g. for different screen size. Always make sure that it looks as expected for all screen sizes.

Comment: Hi Jay, these don't seem to have any effect on the background image, just a foreground one.

Comment: Okay! One way you can move background image is by subclass `UIButton` and there you have to override `func backgroundRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect)`. I am pretty sure this would work for what you are looking for.